# Android : create Login for magento application

Tags: android, magento, authentication, passwords

I want to create login activity to my magento android application, so I get password from user and `password_hash` from `customerCustomerInfo` API. Now how can I compare them ? one of them is hashed and one of normal string

Comment: hash the normal one and compare hashed strings...

Comment: @dagfr did you know what is magento hash format ? is it md5 ?

Comment: this is password : 123456 and this is hash_password that i get from magento :   2364b70e91268d8ecf59fffd47db692b:LSC2VzugdDdUbghTHoTouZeMLxk14OPT  but md5 code for 123456 is : e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e  what is wrong ?

Comment: it depends on your version, it was md5, but newer version may be on SHA256.

Comment: @dagfr thank you , answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772665/magento-password-hash-in-customer-info/20776514#20776514

Comment: right, I read too fast and didn't noticed the ':'.