# Magento password hash in Customer info

Tags: android, magento, hash, md5, hashcode

Hi every body i try to check passwords of users of magento store , i get password from user and magento and try to compare them , one of them is hash code and other is normal string , i want to generate hash of normal one and compare them but problem is magento hashed password is different ! 
this is password : 123456
and this is hash that i get from magento : 2364b70e91268d8ecf59fffd47db692b:LSC2VzugdDdUbghTHoTouZeMLxk14OPT
and this is md5 hash i generate for 123456 : e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e

what is the magento password hashing format ? 
can any body help me ? 
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called a salted password hash.
Split the value you have in your db at `:`. The first part is the salted hash, the second part is the "salt".
In Magento it works like this:

```
$saltedHash = md5($salt.$password);
```

In your case the salt is `LSC2VzugdDdUbghTHoTouZeMLxk14OPT`.
If you try `md5('LSC2VzugdDdUbghTHoTouZeMLxk14OPT123456')`  you get `2364b70e91268d8ecf59fffd47db692b`.
Exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I tried as below , solution is similar but shown in detail here

```
$inDatabase = 2364b70e91268d8ecf59fffd47db692b:LSC2VzugdDdUbghTHoTouZeMLxk14OPT
$passwordEntered = 123456
$hashPassword = explode(':', $inDatabase);
$firstPart = $hashPassword[0];
$salt = $hashPassword[1];
```

Then,
`md5($salt.$passwordEntered)` is equal to `$firstPart`